# SDL2 Window is initialized with a fixed and unchangeable value

Tags: c++, linux, window, sdl-2, i3

I can't seem to specify the size of my window in SDL2 as no matter what value I pass it as width and height it simply ignores it and uses a size of about 850 x 550 px. For example:

```cpp
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 100;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 100;

window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

results on this:
[image: window size example]

[A pastebin to my code if needed](https://pastebin.com/Mn9vAaCb)

Comment: Is this Windows? The title "Testing" doesn't look like Windows.

Comment: This screenshot looks suspicously like a tiling window manager. What WM is that?

Comment: I'm using linux with i3wm, sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your window manager i3wm to treat the window as floating.
You can either do this with a hotkey (the default is apparently "$mod+Shift+Space"), i3wm configuration, or window manager hints.

You *may* achieve the latter by passing an extra flag SDL_WINDOW_UTILITY to the SDL_CreateWindow call.

Comment: The window in question is already in floating mode however, the passed flag didn't change anything aswell.

Comment: Solution is here: http://sdl.5483.n7.nabble.com/unintended-behaviour-SDL-CreateWindow-tp38012p38027.html .  Make the window resizable and it will be tiled as it can be resized to fit to the grid!  Add `| SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` to the last argument of `SDL_CreateWindow`.

Comment: Please post this as an answer instead of a comment , preferably after verification. I was under the impression making it float would be enough, but I was mistaken.